# Angular - after adding nested routed outlet my translation from ngx-translate stopped working

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, router-outlet

I have issue mentioned in title (during this change I didn't change anything in translations).

Main router outlet is made in app component of application, the nested one (child) is in child component, and routing works fine for now.

Sadly, after that implementation my translations no longer working.

Project is quite big, so please tell me what you want me to attach to solve this issue (maybe somebody has something similar).

For example this is shared module for now:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReservationButtonComponent } from './components/reservation-button/reservation-button.component';
import { MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MenuButtonComponent } from './components/menu-button/menu-button.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { PageSectionComponent } from './components/page-section/page-section.component';
import { PageSectionButtonComponent } from './components/page-section/components/page-section-button/page-section-button.component';
import { PageSectionLinkComponent } from './components/page-section/components/page-section-link/page-section-link.component';
import { BookingSectionComponent } from './components/booking-section/booking-section.component';
import { LogoComponent } from './components/logo/logo.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './components/menu/menu.component';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
  }

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ReservationButtonComponent,
    MenuButtonComponent,
    PageSectionComponent,
    PageSectionButtonComponent,
    PageSectionLinkComponent,
    BookingSectionComponent,
    LogoComponent,
    MenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    ReservationButtonComponent,
    MenuButtonComponent,
    PageSectionComponent,
    BookingSectionComponent,
    LogoComponent,
    MenuComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And component inside shared module using translations (before adding nested router outlet it works fine):

```
<div class="booking-popup">
    <img class="booking-rating-image"src="../../../../../assets/logo/booking/Booking.com_logo.svg">
    <div class="booking-rating">{{bookingRating.getNumber()}}</div>
    <div class="booking-rating-text">{{bookingRating.getLabel() | translate }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to init the TranslateModule like this:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (http: HttpClient) =>
          new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', `.json?v=${new Date().getTime()}`),
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
```

Then have your translation files as json files:

```
{
    "demo": {
        "title": "Translation demo",
        "text": "This is a simple demonstration app for ngx-translate"
    }
}
```

Your Component, which sets the language should look something like this:

```js
export class LanguageDropDownComponent implements OnInit {
  supportLanguage = ['de', 'en'];
  language: string = 'en';

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(this.supportLanguage);
    translate.setDefaultLang(this.language);
    this.translate.use(this.language);
  }
  onSelected(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // This is intentional
  }
}
```

In your templates you can access the translation with

```
{{ "demo.title" | translate }}
```

Great extension in VS-Code to prevent any typos are 'Lingua - Managing ngx-translations' and 'ngx-translate-utils'
If you have any further questions let me know.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I tried the above solution and did not work. I further noticed that the problem manifests only on the second subpath. Looks like the translations are correctly loaded, but only the routes on the first group have access to them. The key isabsolutely correct (it is in place of the translated text).